# Correct previous year by id within R

Tags: r

I have data something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,9),Date=c("2013-04","2013-12","2013-01","2013-12","2013-11",
             "2013-12","2012-04","2013-12","2012-08","2014-12","2013-08","2014-12","2013-08","2014-12","2011-01","2013-11","2013-12","2014-01","2014-04"))
```

To get the correct format:

```
df$Date <- paste0(df$Date,"-01")
```

I would need to obtain only `years`, so that each id contains 2 dates following on each other.

I if do on the existing data something like this:

```
require(lubridate)
df$Date <- year(as.Date(df$Date)-days(1))
```

I get sometimes same date for given `id`.

The desired output for the column `Date` is this:

```
 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2013 2014 2013 2014 2013 2014 2011 2013 2014
```

Please note that the last date for given `id` is always correct, so just the preceding year have to be corrected based on the last date. The date have to be in format that can be converted to years only as shown.

**EDIT** Here is the case:

```
Id Date 
1 2013-11-01    
1 2013-12-01     
1 2014-01-01    
1 2014-04-01
```

Now I'm getting this: `2012,2013,2013,2013`

I would need: `2012,2013,2013,2014`

Comment: Please edit you data set and desired output, otherwise its hard to understand what you need

Comment: So it all as before but see the last two dates given Id (9). Actually David your solution I think handles the year 2014 correctly, but just the data.table solution fails on the second part...I'm getting error. So it would be great if that would be within `ave` base R solution.

Comment: @Max I just updated. My previous code gives `[1] 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2013 2014 2013 2014 2013 2014 2011
[16] 2013 2014`.  New code gives `[1] 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2012 2013 2013 2014 2013 2014 2013 2014 2011
[16] 2014 2014`.  I am confused which one you wanted now.

Comment: @Max What I am confused is in your new dataset, the first 2 rows and last 2 rows (just for an example) have the same unique `year`.  So, perhaps you need a better example...

Comment: I know. I'm terribly sorry. Thank you for bearing with me! This is a mess question. I'm just dealing with very bad data. Please see the update, from here it is up to me. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Yes, there are occasion like this, just found out. Which actually completely changes the rules I set in question, I know!

Comment: @Max Suppose you have 3 records..  Also, please make the changes in the `df`

Comment: So the last 4 entries in df$Date are the dates with Id (9).

Comment: @Max Please check if the updated one helps

Comment: Yes, it does work now with some small df cleaning. Thanks a lot and Happy New Year!!!

Comment: You should accept akruns solution then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` using similar approach as @David Arenburg's

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    mutate(year=as.numeric(sub('-.*', '', Date)),
     year=replace(year, n()>1, c(year[2]-1, year[2])))
#    Id    Date year
#1   1 2013-04 2012
#2   1 2013-12 2013
#3   2 2013-01 2012
#4   2 2013-12 2013
#5   3 2013-11 2012
#6   3 2013-12 2013
#7   4 2012-04 2012
#8   4 2013-12 2013
#9   5 2012-08 2013
#10  5 2014-12 2014
#11  6 2013-08 2013
#12  6 2014-12 2014
#13  7 2013-08 2013
#14  7 2014-12 2014
#15  8 2011-01 2011
```

Or using `base R`

```
with(df, ave(as.numeric(sub('-.*', '', Date)), Id, 
     FUN=function(x) if(length(x)>1)(x[2]-1):x[2] else x))

#[1] 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2013 2014 2013 2014 2013 2014 2011
```

#### Update

You can try

```
df$indx <- with(df, ave(Id, Id, FUN=function(x) (seq_along(x)-1)%/%2+1))

with(df, ave(as.numeric(sub('-.*', '', Date)), Id, indx, 
         FUN=function(x) if(length(x)>1)(x[2]-1):x[2] else x)) 
#[1] 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2012 2013 2013 2014 2013 2014 2013 2014 2011
#[16] 2012 2013 2013 2014
```

Or

```
 df %>%
     group_by(Id) %>%
     mutate(year=as.numeric(sub('-.*', '', Date))) %>% 
     group_by(indx=cumsum(rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), length.out=n())), add=TRUE) %>% 
     mutate(year=replace(year, n()>1, c(year[2]-1, year[2])))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I would also prefer to have it in one `call`.  Maybe `DMC's` solution could do that,..

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I was after, with(df, ave(....), FUN) just could not figure out the FUN part :)

Comment: I don't see how DMS'c solution is an improvememnt

Comment: Actually, my data is so particular. After all the best solution I'm getting is within baseR. Please see EDIT 2 if you can.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would solve this using `data.table` package (though it looks over complicated to me)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, year := year(Date)][, 
            year := if(.N == 2) (year[2] - 1):year[2] else year,
            Id][]    

#     Id       Date year indx
#  1:  1 2013-04-01 2012    2
#  2:  1 2013-12-01 2013    2
#  3:  2 2013-01-01 2012    2
#  4:  2 2013-12-01 2013    2
#  5:  3 2013-11-01 2012    2
#  6:  3 2013-12-01 2013    2
#  7:  4 2012-04-01 2012    2
#  8:  4 2013-12-01 2013    2
#  9:  5 2012-08-01 2013    2
# 10:  5 2014-12-01 2014    2
# 11:  6 2013-08-01 2013    2
# 12:  6 2014-12-01 2014    2
# 13:  7 2013-08-01 2013    2
# 14:  7 2014-12-01 2014    2
# 15:  8 2011-01-01 2011    1
```

Or all in one step (thanks to @Arun for providing this):

```
setDT(df)[, year := {tmp = year(Date); 
            if (.N == 2L) (tmp[2]-1L):tmp[2] else tmp},
            Id]
```

---

**Edit**:
Per OPs new data, we can modify the code by adding additional index

```
setDT(df)[, indx := if(.N > 2) rep(seq_len(.N/2), each = 2) + 1L else .N, Id] 
df[, year := {tmp = year(Date); if (.N > 1L) (tmp[2] - 1L):tmp[2] else tmp}, 
     list(Id, indx)][]
#     Id       Date indx year
#  1:  1 2013-04-01    2 2012
#  2:  1 2013-12-01    2 2013
#  3:  2 2013-01-01    2 2012
#  4:  2 2013-12-01    2 2013
#  5:  3 2013-11-01    2 2012
#  6:  3 2013-12-01    2 2013
#  7:  4 2012-04-01    2 2012
#  8:  4 2013-12-01    2 2013
#  9:  5 2012-08-01    2 2013
# 10:  5 2014-12-01    2 2014
# 11:  6 2013-08-01    2 2013
# 12:  6 2014-12-01    2 2014
# 13:  7 2013-08-01    2 2013
# 14:  7 2014-12-01    2 2014
# 15:  8 2011-01-01    1 2011
# 16:  9 2013-11-01    2 2012
# 17:  9 2013-12-01    2 2013
# 18:  9 2014-01-01    3 2013
# 19:  9 2014-04-01    3 2014
```

Or another possible solution provided by @akrun

```
setDT(df)[, `:=`(year = year(Date), indx = .N, indx2 = as.numeric(gl(.N,2, .N))), Id]
df[indx > 1, year:=(year[2]-1):year[2], list(Id, indx2)][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. You can remove the intermediate fields `last_year` and `year2`, but I left them here for clarity:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(
    last_year = last(as.integer(str_sub(Date, 1, 4))),
    year2 = row_number() - n(),
    year = last_year + year2
    )
```